# Delete the oldest five files with cron or launchctl

Tags: cron, find, tar, launchd, rm

I'm currently backing up a project into a tarball. I'd only like to keep the five most recent backups. Currently, the script reads:

```
tar -cjf $HOME/projects/foo.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).tar.bz2 $HOME/projects/foo > /dev/null 2>&1
find $HOME/projects -maxdepth 1 -name "foo*.tar.bz2" | ghead -n -5 | xargs rm > /dev/null 2>&1
# CR and blank line
```

The tarballs are created, but the old ones are never removed. Odd thing is, when I copy and paste the second line into a shell, the files are deleted as expected. The script functions as expected when called manually via the command line. Is the script not reaching the second line, or are there some rules about running commands via `cron` I'm not aware of?

Mac OS X 10.8 with gnu-coreutils. Attempted under `cron` and using launch services, with the same results.

Comment: Usually, cron runs with a much reduced environment than your usual environment and the `PATH` variable also tracks very less number of places. Try Using full path of executable to find, ghead, xargs

Comment: This makes sense. Waiting for the job to be triggered to confirm that it's a solution. Would you like to write this up as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script now works when called from `cron` or an equivalent. Thanks to @ansh0l for the clue.

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

cd $HOME/projects

tar -cjf foo.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).tar.bz2 foo
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "foo*.tar.bz2" | ghead -n -5 | xargs rm
```